# JS fetch() function does not show expected response body even though Chrome DevTools shows it

Tags: javascript, flask, server, fetch-api

I wrote a JS program that sends arguments to a flask server and prints the returned value in the console. The server returns either `[0]` or `[1]` depending on the arguments sent.

However, when this program sends arguments to the server, the resultant fetch() data attribute is always an empty dict `{}` instead of `[0]` or `[1]`. Why is this? In Chrome DevTools, in the Network section, it shows the expected response, but this isn't reflected in fetch()'s data attribute

Code:

```js
function predict(values) {
  fetch(`https://darrendube.pythonanywhere.com/?${stringify(values)}`)
.then((response) => JSON.stringify(response))
.then((data) => console.log(data))
}
```

What is printed in the console:
[image]

What is shown in Chrome DevTools (and the value I expect):
[image]

The fact that DevTools shows the expected response means that the arguments are correct and the server is working normally, so there must be a mistake in my code...

What could it be?

Comment: Did you [read the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)?

Answer (score 4):

The initial Response object does not directly contain the actual JSON response body but is instead a representation of the entire HTTP response. So, to extract the JSON body content from the Response object, we use the json() method.

```
   function predict(values) {
     fetch(`https://darrendube.pythonanywhere.com/?${stringify(values)}`)
   .then((response) => response.json())
   .then((data) => console.log(data))
    }
```